# Custom height of UITableViewCell selected background view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I am going to custom `UITableViewCell` **selected** background view. Here what I have done:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...

  CGRect cellFrame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  CGRect selectedBackgroundFrame = cellFrame;
  UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];

  selectedBackgroundFrame.size.height = 5;
  [selectedBackgroundView setFrame:selectedBackgroundFrame];
  selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0
                                                    green:138/255.0
                                                     blue:171/255.0
                                                    alpha:1];

  NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",
        selectedBackgroundFrame.size.width,
        selectedBackgroundFrame.size.height,
        selectedBackgroundFrame.origin.x,
        selectedBackgroundFrame.origin.y);
  cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;

  return cell;
}
```

But the result is the **selected** background view still populates whole cell, instead of my expectation which is height 5.

It also prints the right thing `320.000000 5.000000 0.000000 0.000000`. What's wrong?

Comment: do you mean, you want to increase the cel height after you select it?

Comment: No, the selectedBackgroundView. Edited my post..

Comment: Can you try to print `selectedBackgroundView.frame`. And does the color of selectedBackgroundView display fine?

Comment: Well I tried to move the code to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and tried to print it, it prints right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might missed below lines in

`ViewDidLoad` While inserting new row, make height consistence.:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = kCellHeight; // Your custom height for cell
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

And also,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return kCellHeight;
}
```

Comment: I want for cell's selectedBackgroundView, not the cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because something somewhere is setting an `autoresizingMask` on the view. Maybe try setting it to `flexibleWidth` and not setting `flexibleHeight` in `cellForRow`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand yours. Could you please explain more?